# how to delete all files with php in a folder when you use an exit after the unlink

Tags: php, exit, unlink

I am using this code to delete all files in a folder and it works fine:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteall'])) {

    $files = glob($dir.'/*'); // get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
        if(is_file($file)) {
          unlink($file); // delete files                               
        }   
    }     
exit;
}
```

When i put the `exit` straight after the `unlink`, like below, it does not work anymore.

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteall'])) {

    $files = glob($dir.'/*'); // get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
       if(is_file($file)) {
       unlink($file); // delete files
       exit;                               
       }   
    }     

}
```

Can someone explain me why the exit must be placed out of the `foreach` loop?
Because after the `unlink`, everything is deleted and you can place an `exit`, but unfortunately....

Comment: Because it otherwise exits after the first iteration, so before all following files are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption of

```
unlink($file); // delete files
//                ************
```

is incorrect.  This is deleting 1 file at a time  You need to let the `foreach` finish so that every file in the directory is deleted.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I do understand it!